# jQuery fadeIn() not working properly

Tags: javascript, jquery

jquery:

```
    $.post("process_login.php",
        {username : $("#username").val(), password : $("#password").val()},
        function(data) {
            $("#login_results").fadeIn("slow").html(data);
            }
        )
```

html:

```
<table>
    <tr><td id="login_results"></td></tr>
    <tr><td><input type="text" id="username" /></td></tr>
    <tr><td><input type="password" id="password" /></td></tr>
    <tr><td><input type="submit" id="login_submit" /></td></tr>
</table>
```

The data shows, but it doesn't fade in. I have no idea why. =/. If you need any other details, let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

probably because you have them in reverse order. you want

```
$("#login_results").html(data).fadeIn("slow");
```

otherwise you're fading in something that doesn't have any content yet.

also, try putting what type of content is being returned by the post request.

```
$.post("page", {params}, function(data){}, "html");
```

after looking at the other answers, the more *complete* answer is to also make login_results invisible first:

```
<td id='login_results' style='display:none'></td>
```

Comment: Nevermind, my reading and comprehension failed me a while ago. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Tables get really finicky when it comes to jquery effects. Inserting the content into a div should do the trick:

```
<table>
    <tr><td><div id="login_results" style="display:none"></div></td></tr>
    <tr><td><input type="text" id="username" /></td></tr>
    <tr><td><input type="password" id="password" /></td></tr>
    <tr><td><input type="submit" id="login_submit" /></td></tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Edited to make sure the div is hidden initially.  fadeIn() does nothing if the element is already visible.

Answer (score 1):

first, make sure that your `#login_results` are not visible by applying a `display: none` on them (either in CSS page or inline, your choice). then try this:

```
$.post("process_login.php",
            {username : $("#username").val(), password : $("#password").val()},
            function(data) {
                    $("#login_results").html(data);
                    $("#login_results").fadeIn('slow');
                    }
            )
```

sometimes chaining doesn't work the way you'd think with certain combination of processes and effects...